# Constructive proof of secure hash collision

Tags: constructive-mathematics, hash-function

The SHA3-512 hash algorithm can be considered as a map *h* from the set *F* of "files" (finite sequences of octets, each octet being an integer in the range 0 to 255) to the set *H* of "hashes" (sequences of 64 octets). I'm curious about proving the non-injectivity of *h*:

Proposition *P*: there exist *a*, *b*, such that *a*≠*b* and *h*(*a*)=*h*(*b*)

*P* seems obviously true to me, because *F* is infinite and *H* is finite. However, nobody knows of any particular *a*,*b* pair. Given that, is there a constructive proof of *P*?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Some people summarize constructive proofs as "proofs that directly provide a specific example". This is not exactly correct: a constructive proof is one that allows you to *produce* a specific example *after putting in some well-defined work*: a constructive proof does not need to give an object with the desired property, just an unambiguous recipe/algorithm for finding an object with the desired property (aside: in terms of proof theory, this additional work amounts to performing [cut-elimination](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cut-elimination_theorem)). With this in mind, we can refine your question into two questions.

**1. Is there a constructive proof that directly provides a specific example $(a,b)$ with $h(a) = h(b)$ and $a \neq b$?**

As of 23 April 2020, we don't know such a proof.

**2. Is there a constructive proof that provides an algorithm for finding such $(a,b)$?**

Sure, there is (although the best one that we know as of 23 April 2020 is quite slow)! Here's such an algorithm. Construct the first $2^{512} + 1$ files, and compute their hashes. Look and see if there are two with the same hash. If so, you can return those two as your result $(a,b)$ and you are done. If not, then you have just constructed $2^{512} + 1$ different elements of the $2^{512}$-element set $H$, so $2^{512} + 1 \leq 2^{512}$. This is a contradiction: [everything follows from a contradiction](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Principle_of_explosion), including the claim that any two files have the same hash, so you can just return your two favorite files $(x,y)$ as your result (this just illustrates the logical structure of the argument: you won't ever find yourself in this second, contradictory case, as you will necessarily find two files with the same hash).

---

---

Does this argument rely on the law of excluded middle? After all, we do a case analysis, our result depends on whether there are two elements with the same hash in our list, i.e. $(\exists a < b < 2^{512} + 1. h(a) = h(b)) \vee (\forall a < b < 2^{512} + 1. h(a) \neq h(b))$, where $h(n)$ denotes the hash of the $n$th file in our list.

Fortunately, $(\exists a < b < 2^{512} + 1. h(a) = h(b)) \vee (\forall a < b < 2^{512} + 1. h(a) \neq h(b))$ is itself a constructively provable theorem. This is intuitively obvious: there's an algorithm that decides which of the two cases holds. Nonetheless, anticipating further objections, I now give an excruciatingly detailed proof of this fact.

We can prove something stronger: $\forall k. (\exists a < b < k. h(a) = h(b)) \vee (\forall a < b < k. h(a) \neq h(b))$ by induction on $k$.  Here's how:

- If $k=0$, then the second disjunct holds vacuously and we are done.
- Otherwise $k=\ell + 1$ for some $\ell \in \mathbb{N}$, and by inductive hypothesis we have $(\exists a < b < \ell. h(a) = h(b)) \vee (\forall a < b < \ell. h(a) \neq h(b))$. We do a proof by cases.

  - In the first case, we have $\exists a < b < \ell. h(a) = h(b)$, so  $\exists a, b < \ell + 1. h(a) = h(b)$ holds *a
    fortiori* and we are done.
  - In the second case, we have $forall a < b < \ell. h(a) \neq h(b)$. We do a case analysis on
    whether $\exists a < \ell. h(a) = h(\ell)$ or $\forall a < \ell. h(a)
       \neq h(\ell)$.

    - In the first case, $\exists a, b < \ell + 1. h(a) =
         h(b)$ holds with $b = \ell$.
    - Otherwise $\forall a < b < \ell + 1.
         h(a) \neq h(b)$ holds since either $b = \ell$, in which case
      $\forall a < \ell. h(a) \neq h(\ell)$ applies, or $b < \ell$, in
      which case the inductive hypothesis $\forall a < b < \ell. h(a) \neq
         h(b)$ applies.

At this point we can ask the question: does this previous argument rely on the law of excluded middle? After all, we do a case analysis on $(\exists a < \ell. h(a) = h(\ell)) \vee (\forall a < \ell. h(a) \neq h(\ell))$. But this again has a constructive proof: there's an algorithm that, given $\ell$, decides which of the disjuncts holds. Nonetheless, I now give an excruciatingly detailed proof.

I shall prove $\forall k. (\exists a < k. h(a) = x) \vee (\forall a < k. h(a) \neq x)$ by induction on $k$ for any fixed hash $x$. Here's how:

- If $k=0$ then the second disjunct holds vacuously and we are done.
- Otherwise $k=\ell+1$ and we have $(\exists a < \ell. h(a) = x) \vee (\forall a < \ell. h(a) \neq x)$ by inductive hypothesis.

  - If the first disjunct holds, we have $\exists a < \ell. h(a) = x)$, so $\exists a < \ell + 1. h(a) = x$ holds *a fortiori*.
  - Otherwise, we have $\forall a < \ell. h(a) \neq x$. We check whether $h(\ell) = x$ or $h(\ell) \neq x$.

    - In the first case, we have $\exists a < \ell + 1. h(a) = x$, with $a = \ell$.
    - In the second case, $\forall a < \ell + 1. h(a) \neq x$ since either $a < \ell$ and the inductive hypothesis applies, or $a = \ell$ and $h(\ell) \neq x$ applies.

At this point we can ask the question: does this previous argument rely on the law of excluded middle? After all, we do case analysis on $h(\ell) = x$. But this works because hashes are just whole numbers, and you can decide if two whole numbers are equal by just comparing them. More formally, $\forall x,y \in \mathbb{N}. x = y \vee x \neq y$ is a theorem of [constructive arithmetic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heyting_arithmetic), but one that I now leave as an exercise for the reader.

Comment: I'm not yet convinced by this. Your proof is of the form "if so" / "if not", so it seems to rely on the law of the excluded middle.

Comment: @AshleyYakeley I have added a very detailed proof showing why this does not rely on excluded middle, even though I think you're trolling. I find it utterly implausible that you know about SHA512 but don't see how to write a program that decides if a finite list contains two equal elements.

Comment: OK, this is helpful. Can you also constructively prove that $\forall a < b < 2^{512} + 1. h(a) \neq h(b)$ leads to a contradiction?

Comment: Not trolling! Please feel free at any time to accuse me of ignorance.

Comment: Have you tried proving it yourself?!

If $\{h(a_1) \neq h(a_2) \dots h(a_{k+1}) \neq h(a_{k+2})\} \subseteq H$ and $|H|=k+1$, then $\{h(a_1),h(a_2),\dots h(a_{k+1})\} \subseteq H \setminus \{ h(a_{k + 2}) \}$ and $|H\setminus \{ h(a_{k + 2}) \}| = k$. We also have that $\{h(a_1)\} \subseteq \emptyset$ is a contradiction, since it implies $h(a_1) \in \emptyset$, which contradicts $\forall x. x \not\in \emptyset$.

You can turn this into a proof-by-induction to conclude this for all $k$, then take $k= 2^{512} + 1$. If you get stuck somewhere, you can always ask another question on this site.

Answer (score 0):

The constructive proof involves an algorithm that constructs $2^{512}+1$ distinct files, say $F_0, \ldots F_{2^{512}+1}$, calculates their SHA3-512 hash values and then searches for $i \neq j$ such that $h(F_i) = h(F_j)$. This algorithm is guaranteed to terminate by the pigeon-hole principle, but the running time is infeasible in the real world.

A constructive proof giving an algorithm that had a feasible running time would expose a flaw in the design of the SHA3-513 algorithm. We hope that no such algorithm exists, but, as happens so often in cryptographical questions of this kind, we have no proof of that.

Comment: Does this algorithm need to be actually run, and i,j obtained, before the constructivist is satisfied of P?